# SQL Server stalls for ten minutes

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I manage an ASP.NET MVC 3 website with multiple online transactions. In the website, customers can place orders, pay bills while vendors can bill customers. All this can happen simultaneously so I have semaphores to ensure thread safety.

What I have noticed is that about once a week, the website stalls for ten minutes. My first tought was for deadlocks in the semaphores, but after putting in place a semaphore log and analysing the results, there seems to be no deadlocks. Also, the website comes back by itself after ten minutes.

While investigating, I noticed that the entire website becomes irresponsive and not just the parts using the semaphores. They all use the database tough. That is why my primary suspect is the database.

What is stranger is that every time, the website freeze for ten minutes almost to the second. Could SQL Server have a scheduled maintenance or anything that could explain this delay? If not, do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Its sounds like a scheduled (bad) maintenance, but this are not by default, some one install it.

Comment: Are you running out of available connections to SQL?  This can happen if the connections are not being closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question seems to be "yes".  Something is happening in the environment that is locking things up.

Have you run sp_who2 to see what is running when it stalls?

If that is inconvenient, then set up a job to dump sp_who2 output into a table every five minutes.  When it stalls, you can see what is running and work from there.

I have faced what may be a similar problem, where the master database seems to be getting locked up.  As a consequence, renaming databases does not work.  Fortunately, this is not in a live transaction environemnt, so waiting five minutes and trying again does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Hangs can happen for a variety of reasons. Typically you get Connection or Command timeouts when you have problems with SQL not hangs.

You're much better off

- Grabbing the Debugging [Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)
- Use AdPlus to grab a memory dump (`adplus -hang -pn processname.exe`) or DebugDiag and setup a dump rule
- Use WinDbg (or VS 2010 for 4.0 framework) (after you set up a symbol cache)  and start examining what's happening using
  `!threads` or `!dumpheap -stat` to inspect the threads and the heap objects.

Please note debugging production issues is very hard and WinDbg is not a friendly tool but guessing and looking at logs is even less so.